# DAX Virtual tables - don't work... SUMX doesn't work

Tags: filter, sum, powerbi, dax

OK - I've tried to simplify this as much as possible and isolate to just one set of data, here is my measure --- You really only have to pay attention to the first Var and the Return:

```
    Optimal Wkld2 =
VAR summarizedtableTooMuch =
    ADDCOLUMNS (
        SUMMARIZE (
            FILTER (
                Performance,
                SUMX ( performance, Performance[Inv L4Wks] )
                    - SUMX ( performance, Performance[OD Inventory] ) >= 0
            ),
            Performance[MCO]
        ),
        "OD Inventory2", CALCULATE ( SUMX ( performance, Performance[OD Inventory] ) ),
        "Act Inv", CALCULATE ( SUMX ( performance, Performance[Inv L4Wks] ) ),
        "Act Trans", CALCULATE ( SUMX ( performance, Performance[Trans Last 4 wks] ) ),
        "NewTrans", 1 * CALCULATE ( SUMX ( performance, Performance[Trans Last 4 wks] ) ),
        "NewWkld",
            (
                1 * CALCULATE ( SUMX ( performance, Performance[Trans Last 4 wks] ) )
                    / CALCULATE ( SUMX ( performance, Performance[OD Inventory] ) )
            ),
        "Cat", 1
    )
VAR summarizedtableTooLittle =
    FILTER (
        ADDCOLUMNS (
            SUMMARIZE ( Performance, Performance[MCO] ),
            "OD Inventory", CALCULATE ( SUM ( Performance[OD Inventory] ) ),
            "Act Inv", CALCULATE ( SUM ( Performance[Inv L4Wks] ) ),
            "Act Trans", CALCULATE ( SUM ( Performance[Trans Last 4 wks] ) ),
            "NewTrans",
                CALCULATE ( SUM ( Performance[Trans Last 4 wks] ) )
                    * (
                        1
                            + ABS (
                                CALCULATE (
                                    ( SUM ( Performance[Inv L4Wks] ) - SUM ( Performance[OD Inventory] ) )
                                        / SUM ( Performance[OD Inventory] )
                                )
                            )
                    ),
            "NewWkld",
                (
                    (
                        CALCULATE ( SUM ( Performance[Trans Last 4 wks] ) )
                            * (
                                1
                                    + ABS (
                                        CALCULATE (
                                            ( SUM ( Performance[Inv L4Wks] ) - SUM ( Performance[OD Inventory] ) )
                                                / SUM ( Performance[OD Inventory] )
                                        )
                                    )
                            )
                    )
                        / CALCULATE ( SUM ( Performance[OD Inventory] ) )
                ),
            "Cat", 0
        ),
        SUM ( Performance[Inv L4Wks] ) - SUM ( Performance[OD Inventory] ) < 0
    )
VAR totalsummary =
    UNION ( summarizedtableTooMuch, summarizedtableTooLittle )
RETURN
    CALCULATE (
        SUMX ( FILTER ( summarizedtableTooMuch, [Cat] = 1 ), [OD Inventory2] )
    )
```

So you see I have pulled in HALF the data from a variable table - my filter inside the first Summarize should reduce that table to at least half of the data.

here is what I get from my "Return"

1. All rows that should have been filtered out are blank
2. All data that is in each row and not blank - is correct
3. The Power Bi TOTAL at the bottom is a total of the entire dataset...  ????  WTF??????  I filtered the variable table it's coming from...??

In the below picture you can see the correct blanks in the rows, as well as the rows of data...  The correct total should be ~35K

Please don't suggest "Values" or "Calculated table":

1. I cannot do "Sum(Values(table[COL])" because it's a virtual table... if I can please let me know how.
2. I cannot do a calculated table as the calculations will change based on filtering criteria on
   the visualization.

This is asking me to write more details... I don't have any, please help I have tried everything... which is why there are so many filters all over the code and why the code is so long for what it's doing.  Please help this is so stupid that this is not more straight-forward.  If someone at MSFT is reading this, please fix your S%@t, I've wasted 2 days on this in various forms of the same issue.

[Stupid Power Bi Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XcOwW.png)

Comment: If you can go [here](https://community.powerbi.com/), create a sample pbix and describe what you are trying to achieve. Stack does not allow sharing data through upload URL. I am sure you will be helped in no time and very efficiently.

Comment: First of all, you need to stay professional. The way you end your question screams anger and frustration, which I understand, but doesn't help you get an answer. Secondly, why aren't you using measures for this instead of making this big table? If you split everything into different measures, it is easier to find a problem and also it is easier in the future to change calculations when necessary. If you could supply some sample data, the output you get now ánd the expected output, I would be willing to help.